# How to merge Python pandas data frames on multiple keys

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have two data frames A and B. If I want to do an inner join only if the intersection rows has equal relationship from multiple columns in both A and B, i.e, these columns combined are the matching criteria. How should I start? These two dataframes are large. Thanks

Update: use concat function, with dataframes includes in list as parameter, axis=1. Hope it can help others

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging)?

Comment: If still unclear after reading the docs, please revise your question to include a sample of your dataframe and the result you want to achieve. It'll maximize your chances to get appropriate help.